# How is 納める used here?

Tags: meaning

> 奉納とは　神仏に喜んで納めてもらうために物品を供えたり、その前で芸能・競技などを行ったりすること。

(from [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/202399/meaning/m0u/%E5%A5%89%E7%B4%8D/))

It seems to make sense without 納める. What meaning does it add / how is it used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 納める is a verb which means "(for 神仏) to receive". It's definition 2 in [this entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/30841/meaning/m0u/):

> ２ 金や物などを受け取って自分のものとする。手に入れる。受納する。獲得する。**「薄志ですが、―・めてください」**「勝利を―・める」「手中に―・める」

So "神仏に喜んで納めてもらうために" means "so that 神仏 receive them delightedly."

Note that 納める also means "to offer", "to pay" or "to put in" in most cases (see definitions 1 and 3). Perhaps it's an example of [auto-antonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym). This ("神仏が物品を納める") is an example of the less common usage of the verb.